# How to connect nodejs to SQL Server

Tags: node.js, sql-server, connection

When I am trying to connect nodejs to SQL Server, I get an error - please help to sort out this

My configuration:

```
const config ={
    user:'sa',
    password:'ponmani',
    server:'localhost',
    database:'Students',
    options:{
        trustedconnection: true,
        encrypt: false,
        enableArithAbort: true,
        instancename:'PONMANI'
    },
    port:63022
}
```

My instance name: `PONMANI\PONMANI`

[image]

Please can someone explain from where I need to get port number correctly and also by default can we use server as localhost?

[image]

This is the error I get:

> ConnectionError: Login failed for user 'sa'.
>
> at Connection. (E:\Nodejslearning\samplenode\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:68:17)
> at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:417:26)
> at Connection.emit (events.js:310:20)
> at Connection.message (E:\Nodejslearning\samplenode\node_modules\mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:2148:18)
> at Connection.dispatchEvent (E:\Nodejslearning\samplenode\node_modules\mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1279:15)
> at MessageIO. (E:\Nodejslearning\samplenode\node_modules\mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1139:14)
> at MessageIO.emit (events.js:310:20)
> at Message. (E:\Nodejslearning\samplenode\node_modules\mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\message-io.js:46:14)
> at Message.emit (events.js:322:22)
> at endReadableNT (E:\Nodejslearning\samplenode\node_modules\mssql\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_readable.js:1094:12) {
> code: 'ELOGIN',

Comment: Check with SQL Server Error log. Execute the below in SSMS 
Exec xp_readerrorlog 0,1,N'Listen'

So, You will get an Idea on which PORT your instance listening to

Comment: `IPAll` is the address, `0.0.0.0`. Since your connection configuration has server set to `localhost` what port/s do you have listening on the localhost loopback address, `127.0.0.1`?